# Where to find this type of chain guide?

Tags: chain-guide

As the title says, where can I get this type of chain guide? My chain falls off exactly at the bottom side of chainring when I'm making bigger jumps and this would be the perfect solution for that. [image: chain guide]

Comment: I've never seen one in the flesh.  And your problem sounds more like one of tooth capacity or chain length.

Comment: Check your chainring for bends - use a ruler or straightedge across tangents and see where its not flat.  I bet it drops the chain at a subtle bend.  A keeper like this will just rub if the bend is inward, or will catch the fallen chain after it comes off but trap it between keeper and chainring.  You're trying to fix a symptom when the root cause is different.

Comment: Looks cheap and does not look like it would actually not stop the chain coming off. Look for a chain guide with an idler wheel.

Comment: Check the tension of the chain. Too much slack causes the chains to fall off. Also, stand behind you bike and look from the cogs towards the chain ring and make sure the chain is following a straing line.